# how to write the match keyword in routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

```
http://localhost:4500/clients/client_show?mac_id=f8:e0:79:9b:bb:58&nas_id=00:11:22:33:44:55
```

I want to convert this url into

```
http://localhost:4500/clients/client_show/f8:e0:79:9b:bb:58/00:11:22:33:44:55
```

For this how can i write the path in routes.rb, Advance thanks..

Answer (score 1):

It follows this pattern:

```
match 'photos', to: 'photos#show', via: [:get, :post]
```

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
get '/clients/client_show/:mac_id/:nas_id', to: 'clients#client_show'
```

Then you have access to it via

```
params[:mac_id] and params[:nas_id]
```